# GXT live grid not scrolling to bottom

Tags: gxt

I have a GXT LiveGridView grid - works great, loading fine, but will not scroll all the way to the bottom record using the scroll bar.  The only way to see the last record is to select the last visible record and use the down arrow key to force the display down, one record at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By overriding the 'getCalculatedRowHeight' method, since it was returning a wrong value (compared with the Firebug analysis) the issue was resolved.

```
private class MyLiveGridView<T> extends LiveGridView<T> {
    // deal with wrong value of 22 from this method currently.
    @Override
    protected int getCalculatedRowHeight(){
        return 28;
    }
}
```

(A real fix would be to dynamically acquire the correct row height.  For now this will suffice since I'm on the hook for a lot of code still).